# Async client service design pattern

Tags: c#, service, .net-4.0, tcpclient

I'm trying to design a mail client service which allows connecting and sending/receiving commands using the TcpClient class.  I also want to automatically invoke the calling thread upon callback of each function so that the caller doesn't need to.

I am finding that I need to write at least three to four times more code per function in order to implement this than if I were to write it synchronously.  The biggest problem is that I have to write a separate try/catch for every single callback.

I'll post my Connect function and hopefully someone can suggest a better way:

```
public virtual void Connect(Action<Exception> callback, string hostname, int port, bool ssl, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validateCertificate)
{
    if (State != ConnectionState.Disconnected)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(AlreadyConnectedString);

    Host = hostname;
    Port = port;
    Ssl = ssl;

    var context = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    // Callback on the caller's thread
    Action<Exception> onCallback = (Exception ex) =>
        {
            context.Post(_ =>
                {
                    callback(ex);
                }, null);
        };

    // Called on any raised exceptions
    Action<Exception> onFail = (Exception ex) =>
        {
            State = ConnectionState.Disconnected;
            Cleanup();
            onCallback(ex);
        };

    // Check for a valid response
    Action<string, Exception> onConnectResponse = (string response, Exception ex) =>
        {
            if (ex != null)
                onFail(ex);

            try
            {
                OnConnected(response);
                onCallback(ex);
            }
            catch (Exception responseException)
            {
                onFail(responseException);
            }
        };

    // Callback after SSL authentication
    AsyncCallback onAuthenticated = (IAsyncResult result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                var sslStream = (SslStream)result.AsyncState;
                sslStream.EndAuthenticateAsClient(result);

                State = ConnectionState.Authorization;

                GetResponse(onConnectResponse);
            }
            catch (Exception authenticateException)
            {
                onFail(authenticateException);
            }
        };

    // Callback after TcpClient connect
    AsyncCallback onConnect = (IAsyncResult result) =>
        {
            try
            {
                _Connection.EndConnect(result);

                _Stream = _Connection.GetStream();

                if (ssl)
                {
                    SslStream sslStream;

                    if (validateCertificate != null)
                        sslStream = new SslStream(_Stream, false, validateCertificate);
                    else
                        sslStream = new SslStream(_Stream, false);

                    _Stream = sslStream;

                    sslStream.BeginAuthenticateAsClient(hostname, onAuthenticated, sslStream);
                }
                else
                {
                    State = ConnectionState.Authorization;

                    GetResponse(onConnectResponse);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception connectException)
            {
                onFail(connectException);
            }
        };

    try
    {
        _Connection = new TcpClient();
        _Connection.BeginConnect(hostname, port, onConnect, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        onFail(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a network library to do this for you? Checkout http://www.networkcomms.net/how-to-create-a-client-server-application-in-minutes/. Disclaimer - I'm a developer for this library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the general format of code I have used so far successfully.

It doesn't block the calling thread (UI) and it always invokes its callbacks on the calling thread, but it does the bulk of the work of each task in background threads.

If a thread needs exclusive access to a shared resource (such as an open network/SSL stream) then you can use a locker to marshal use of this resource so only one thread uses it at a time.

```
public void Connect(Action<Exception> callback, string hostname, int port, bool ssl, RemoteCertificateValidationCallback validateCertificate)
{
    if (State != ConnectionState.Disconnected)
        throw new InvalidOperationException(AlreadyConnectedString);

    Host = hostname;
    Port = port;
    Ssl = ssl;
    State = ConnectionState.Connecting;

    var callingThread = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

    Action connectAction = () =>
    {
        // Connect asynchronously in order to specify a timeout
        TcpClient connection = new TcpClient();
        connection.SendTimeout = SendTimeout;
        connection.ReceiveTimeout = ReadTimeout;

        IAsyncResult ar = connection.BeginConnect(hostname, port, null, null);
        WaitHandle waitHandle = ar.AsyncWaitHandle;

        try
        {
            if (!ar.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(ConnectTimeout), false))
                throw new TimeoutException();

            connection.EndConnect(ar);
        }
        finally
        {
            waitHandle.Close();
        }

        Stream stream = connection.GetStream();

        if (ssl)
        {
            SslStream sslStream;

            if (validateCertificate != null)
                sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false, validateCertificate);
            else
                sslStream = new SslStream(stream, false);

            sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(hostname);

            stream = sslStream;
        }

        lock (_locker) // Perform thread unsafe operations here
        {
            _connection = connection;
            _stream = stream;
        }

        OnConnected(GetResponse());
    };

    Action<Task> completeAction = (Task task) =>
    {
        Exception ex = (task.Exception != null) ? task.Exception.InnerException : task.Exception;

        if (task.Exception != null)
        {
            Cleanup();
        }
        else
        {
            State = ConnectionState.Authorization;
        }

        if (callback != null)
            callback(ex);
    };

    Task.Factory.StartNew(connectAction, CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
                .ContinueWith(completeAction, callingThread);
}
```